# ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(999)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
follow = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='#main > div > div.Root__top-container > div.Root__main-view > div.main-view-container > div.os-host.os-host-foreign.os-theme-spotify.os-host-resize-disabled.os-host-scrollbar-horizontal-hidden.main-view-container__scroll-node.os-host-transition.os-host-overflow.os-host-overflow-y > div.os-padding > div > div > div.main-view-container__scroll-node-child > main > section > div > div.BL__GuO2JsHMR6RgNfwY > div.DaUpbHuRI9KWD6hlZKk3.contentSpacing > div > button.aAr9nYtPsG7P2LRzciXc')
```

follow.click

I get here the error this line

Comment: is this error **interrupt** your test execution ?

Comment: yes bro thit it